# What is the term for requiring a user to go through an additional activation/verification process on new devices only?

Tags: authentication, terminology

When I log onto my bank's website on a new device (be it a new phone or a web browser I haven't used before) it prompts me to send an activation code to my phone or email. I have to enter in this one-time code before it will let me log in.

The next time I log in I don't have to do this, unless something happened like I cleared out all my cookies or something. I may even have multi-factor authentication turned on to where I need to do something else like enter in another phrase or a code from a dongle or something but I don't have to do the verification code through a text message or other means unless something changes to my browser/device situation.

What is the term for this? Most of the ____factor Authentication terms are referring to needing to do something every time, I'm just wondering if there's a term for when you only need to do it on new devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This falls under the area of **Adaptive Authentication**, although that term covers the whole package - deciding who you are based on multiple factors, and getting more reassurance using multiple resources, including pushing out cookies to act as a factor in future authentications.

A couple of well known examples are:

- [RSA Adaptive Authentication](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-fraud-prevention/rsa-adaptive-authentication.htm)
- [OpenAM / ForgeRock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAM)

Determining if you're coming from a device that the server knows about is a "device cookie" in ForgeRock or "device identification" in RSA.  But, really, they have multiple factors that they assign weights to when deciding to trust you:

- Have there been failed authentications for this account?
- Is the client IP address on a whitelist?
- Is the client IP address in a good geolocation?
- Has the account logged in from this IP previously?
- Is the device recognized from past logins (e.g., device cookie?)
- How long has it been since this account last logged in?

Coming from a recognized device is weighted heavily, so if that device cookie is missing you often have to do the work to get it.  But it's quite possible to write a policy where that isn't the case, given the variety of checks you can use in determining trust.